# Regex: A-Z characters only

Tags: c#, regex

Hi guys I have a string for example...

"Afds 1.2 45002"

What I wanted to do using regex is to start from the left, return characters A-Z || a-z until an unmatached is encountered.

So in the example above  I wanted to return "Afds".

Another example

"BCAD 2.11 45099 GHJ"

In this case I just want "BCAD".

Thanks

Comment: [a..zA..z] this is all you need

Comment: @loldop: This will match anywhere in the string, and only one character.

Comment: `new string(input.TakeWhile(char.IsLetter).ToArray())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this regular expression `(?i)^[a-z]+`

```
Match match = Regex.Match(stringInput, @"(?i)^[a-z]+");
```

`(?i)` - ignore case

`^` - begin of string

`[a-z]` - any latin letter

`[a-z ]` - any latin letter or space

`+` - 1 or more previos symbol

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Your Solution looks good I wrote a unit test to test for the following string... "I love you 999" this returned "I", Ideally i would like "I love you". Thanks

Comment: it's not a-z only use this one `(?i)^[a-z ]+`

Comment: Thank you that worked! Could explain that pattern to me please for future reference.

Answer (score 6):

The expression you want is: `/^([A-Za-z]+)/`

Comment: your regex will match only upper-case.

Comment: @quarry - seriously, a down-vote for an obvious oversight? never the less, its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sInput = "Afds 1.2 45002";

Match match = Regex.Match(sInput, @"^[A-Za-z]+",
              RegexOptions.None);

// Here we check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
{
    // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```