# A regex expression in C# help needed

Tags: c#, regex

My current regex looks somewhat like this:

```
(?<name>[\w\-"]+)[ \n]+MODULE-IDENTITY
```

It searches for MODULE-IDENTITY and then returns the word (with - and " symbols) that comes before. Now i want to add something that will check if the word before MODULE-IDENTITY is lets say DOG it wont result in a match.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you put an real exemple of your text file and the result you want pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific example:

```
(?<name>[\w\-"]+)(?<!DOG)[ \n]+MODULE-IDENTITY
```

This will match e.g.

testing

MODULE-IDENTITY

but not

DOG

MODULE-IDENTITY

Answer (score 0):

this is the regEx that exclude the word `dog`

```
(?<name>\b(?!\bdog\b)[\w\-"]+\b+)[ \n]+MODULE-IDENTITY
```

I use word boundary `\b` to allow the RegEx to match words like `hot-dog` that contains the word to exclude

try it with http://regexhero.net/tester/

if you put input
`hi cat MODULE-IDENTITY test` --> `match found "cat MODULE-IDENTITY"`
and if you input
`hi dog MODULE-IDENTITY test` --> `no matches found`

`c#` code

```
string strRegex = @"(?<name>\b(?!\bdog\b)[\w\-""]+\b+)[ \n]+MODULE-IDENTITY";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
string strTargetString = @"hi dog MODULE-IDENTITY test";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // in this case no matches found because of "dog" word in input
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way write the regular expression to check for any words before the MODULE-IDENTITY is given in:[Regex: A-Z characters only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815835/regex-a-z-characters-only)
However you need to have a IsMatch check, like:
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern,    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), where s is your input string, sPattern is your regular expression, and the last argument are some options for making the match.